# Spark 2.4.0 functions.udf not working for collections

Tags: apache-spark

The below code used to work fine in Spark versions (2.*) prior to 2.4.0

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object MyApp extends App {

  val spark = SparkSession.builder
    .appName("udf check").master("local[*]").getOrCreate
  import spark.implicits._

  val initDf = spark.read
    .option("delimiter", "|")
    .csv("input.txt")
    .select($"_c0".alias("person"), split($"_c1", ",").alias("friends"))
  //udf's
  val reverse_friends_name = udf((friends: Seq[String]) => friends.map(_.reverse))
  val flatten = udf((listOfFriends: Seq[Seq[String]]) => listOfFriends.flatten.toList)

  initDf.groupBy("person").agg(reverse_friends_name(flatten(collect_set("friends")))).show

}
```

Below is the input

```
sam|jenny,miller
miller|joe
sam|carl
joe|frank
```

Output generated:

```
+------+------------------------------------+
|person|UDF(UDF(collect_set(friends, 0, 0)))|
+------+------------------------------------+
|miller|                               [eoj]|
|   joe|                             [knarf]|
|   sam|                [ynnej, rellim, l...|
+------+------------------------------------+
```

But with Spark 2.4.0, the below code breaks

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object MyApp extends App {

  val spark = SparkSession.builder
    .appName("udf check").master("local[*]").getOrCreate
  import spark.implicits._

  val initDf = spark.read
    .option("delimiter", "|")
    .csv("input.txt")
    .select($"_c0".alias("person"), split($"_c1", ",").alias("friends"))
  //udf
  val reverse_friends_name = udf((friends: Seq[String]) => friends.map(_.reverse))

  initDf.groupBy("person").agg(reverse_friends_name(flatten(collect_set("friends")))).show

}
```

generates below error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.runtime.LazyRef
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: scala.runtime.LazyRef, value: LazyRef thunk)
    - element of array (index: 2)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 3)
    - field (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, name: capturedArgs, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, SerializedLambda[capturingClass=class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF, functionalInterfaceMethod=scala/Function1.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, implementation=invokeStatic org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/ScalaUDF.$anonfun$f$2:(Lscala/Function1;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/Expression;Lscala/runtime/LazyRef;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/InternalRow;)Ljava/lang/Object;, instantiatedMethodType=(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/InternalRow;)Ljava/lang/Object;, numCaptured=3])
    - writeReplace data (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$$Lambda$1841/822958001, org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$$Lambda$1841/822958001@e097c13)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF, name: f, type: interface scala.Function1)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF, UDF(flatten(collect_set(friends#15, 0, 0)#20)))
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Alias, name: child, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Alias, UDF(flatten(collect_set(friends#15, 0, 0)#20)) AS UDF(flatten(collect_set(friends, 0, 0)))#21)
    - element of array (index: 1)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 2)
    - field (class: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer, name: array, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer, ArrayBuffer(person#14, UDF(flatten(collect_set(friends#15, 0, 0)#20)) AS UDF(flatten(collect_set(friends, 0, 0)))#21))
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectHashAggregateExec, name: resultExpressions, type: interface scala.collection.Seq)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectHashAggregateExec, ObjectHashAggregate(keys=[person#14], functions=[collect_set(friends#15, 0, 0)], output=[person#14, UDF(flatten(collect_set(friends, 0, 0)))#21])
```

I was not able to find much documentation pointing to this feature. Was it removed in order to support the added functions for collections?

Comment: It works fine when I test in 2.4.0. Have you tried restarting cluster/spark session?

Comment: I am running directly from Scala IDE in local mode. What I am suspecting is in my older code I was using Scala 2.11, but in new version I changed to Scala 2.12. I am yet to verify that.

Comment: @Shasankar do you remember how you got around this? Also upgraded to 2.4.4/2.12 and facing this

Answer (score 0):

if your code is throwing above error, then change your spark library versions from 2.12 to 2.11..
Everything will run.

In my case I was using 3.x version of spark where 2.12 is default,, I switched to 2.4 with 2.11 and everything worked....